# How to select more than one row per group in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Here is my table "puntos":

```
  Equipo      Liga  Puntos
---------------------------
 At. Madrid     1     68
 Espanyol       1     64
 Barcelona      1     63
 Real Madrid    1     61
 Castellón      1     48
 Murcia         2     78
 Elche          2     70
 Sevilla        2     60
 Valladolid     2     57
```

I just want to get two rows per different value of the attribute "Liga", the two that have the greatest values of "Puntos" group by "Liga".

So it should return something like that:

```
 Equipo      Liga  Puntos
---------------------------
 At. Madrid     1     68
 Espanyol       1     64
 Murcia         2     78
 Elche          2     70
```

I get the result with that query:

```
SELECT * FROM puntos GROUP BY Liga HAVING max(puntos) 
UNION
SELECT p1.Equipo, p1.Liga, max(p1.puntos) FROM puntos p1, (SELECT * FROM puntos GROUP BY Liga HAVING max(puntos) ORDER BY Liga,puntos DESC) p2
WHERE p1.Liga=p2.Liga AND p1.puntos<p2.puntos GROUP BY Liga
ORDER BY Liga,puntos DESC
```

But that solution that not works if the select values of column "puntos" are equal.

Is there any other way to do it for any value, equal or not?

Comment: What should happen if teams are tied in a league? If, for example, Sevilla and Elche both had 70 points, behind Murcia's 78?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use [9.4 User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html):

```sql
SELECT
  `der`.`Equipo`,
  `der`.`Liga`,
  `der`.`Puntos` 
FROM (
  SELECT
    `p`.`Equipo`,
    `p`.`Liga`,
    `p`.`Puntos`,
    IF(@`prev_liga` != `p`.`Liga`,
        @`rownum` := 1,
        @`rownum` := @`rownum` + 1
    ) `rank`,
    @`prev_liga` := `p`.`Liga`
  FROM (
    SELECT
      `Equipo`,
      `Liga`,
      `Puntos`
    FROM `puntos`
    GROUP BY `Liga`, `Puntos`
    ORDER BY `Liga`, `Puntos` DESC   
  ) `p`, (SELECT
            @`rownum` := NULL,
            @`prev_liga` := 0) `r`
) `der`
WHERE `der`.`rank` <= 2
ORDER BY `der`.`Liga`, `der`.`rank`;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f031/1)</kbd>

Two teams from the same "Liga" equal "Puntos":

```sql
SELECT
  `der`.`Equipo`,
  `der`.`Liga`,
  `der`.`Puntos` 
FROM (
  SELECT
    `p`.`Equipo`,
    `p`.`Liga`,
    `p`.`Puntos`,
    IF(@`prev_liga` != `p`.`Liga`,
        @`rownum` := 1,
        @`rownum` := @`rownum` + 1
    ) `rank`,
    @`prev_liga` := `p`.`Liga`
  FROM (
    SELECT
      `Equipo`,
      `Liga`,
      `Puntos`
    FROM `puntos`
    ORDER BY `Liga`, `Puntos` DESC   
  ) `p`, (SELECT
            @`rownum` := NULL,
            @`prev_liga` := 0) `r`
) `der`
WHERE `der`.`rank` <= 2
ORDER BY `der`.`Liga`, `der`.`rank`;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94220/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

First, this solution will only work if `Equipo` is unique across all leagues. If not - you should add `equipoID` and use it instead.

Now, we first select the leader of each league. Then create a union with the same select again, only using the WHERE to filter out the teams that we've already got on our first union. That will essentially give us the follower.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM puntos ORDER BY `liga`,`puntos` DESC) `leader`
GROUP BY `liga`

UNION
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM puntos ORDER BY `liga`,`puntos` DESC) `follower`
WHERE `follower`.`equipo` NOT IN 
  (SELECT equipo FROM
    (SELECT * FROM puntos ORDER BY `liga`,`puntos` DESC) `leader`
   GROUP BY `liga`
  )
GROUP BY `liga`
ORDER BY `liga`
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the max puntos

```
SELECT Equipo, Liga, max(Puntos) Puntos FROM results GROUP BY Liga
```

Then remove the maximum by Liga from the points and get the maximum again

```
SELECT Equipo, Liga, max(Puntos) Puntos FROM results A 
    WHERE Puntos NOT IN 
    (SELECT max(Puntos) Puntos FROM results B 
     WHERE A.LIGA = B.LIGA 
     GROUP BY Liga)
    GROUP BY Liga
```

The wrap the whole select to order the columns

```
SELECT Equipo, Liga, Puntos
FROM
(SELECT Equipo, Liga, max(Puntos) Puntos FROM results GROUP BY Liga
UNION 
SELECT Equipo, Liga, max(Puntos) Puntos FROM results A 
WHERE Puntos NOT IN 
(SELECT max(Puntos) Puntos FROM results B 
 WHERE A.LIGA = B.LIGA
 GROUP BY Liga)
GROUP BY Liga)  T
ORDER BY Liga ASC, Puntos DESC
```

Check the [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2e122/2).

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I will suggest little different approach to this problem.

```
SET @num := 0, @liga := 0;

SELECT Equipo, Liga, Puntos
FROM (SELECT Equipo, Liga, Puntos, @num := if(@liga = Liga, @num + 1, 1) AS rowNumber,
              @liga := Liga
      FROM (SELECT Equipo, Liga, Puntos
            FROM results
            ORDER BY Liga, Puntos DESC) t1) tx
WHERE rowNumber <= 2;
```

Also here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d65e5/13) to see how it's work...

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372841/mysql-greatest-n-results-with-join-tables/29400090#29400090) you can take a look at one of my previous (very similar answer)!

GL!